# Обновление записей в RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, pdo, redbeanphp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Обработчик]Всем привет, я хочу сделать так чтобы можно было редактировать различные записи на странице путём sql запроса R::exec. И у меня почему то не хочет работать путём получения id $_GET['id'], если я пишу например id=67 всё работает
Вот код:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
```

R::exec("UPDATE `addsub` SET title='$data[title]', textless='$data[textless]', author='$data[author]' WHERE id='$id'");

}

Comment: так GET или POST?

Comment: $id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: Посмотрите `print_r`, что вообще получается в строке запроса перед отправкой в `R::exec`

Comment: выводит просто 0

Comment: `print_r("UPDATE addsub SET title='$data[title]', textless='$data[textless]', author='$data[author]' WHERE id='$id'")` выводит 0? или `print_r($d)` выводит 0?

Comment: UPDATE addsub SET title='ddd', textless='', author='' WHERE id=''

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно первый раз сделал)

Comment: Ну так проблема не в приложенном вами коде. Судя по всему вы либо не так получаете `$id`, либо не передаете его в запросе. Добавьте в вопрос весь код, который касается этой проблемы, и строку http запроса, которым вызываете скрипт

Comment: Судя по коду и по выводу `print_r`, не передан `?id=67` в запросе. Что в `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: $_GET  Array ( )

Comment: В скрипт не передано ни одного GET параметра, от куда же взялся id